# Recommended dev process using PhoneGap & Sencha Touch?

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch

I'm about to start writing an application using PhoneGap & Sencha Touch 2. At first stage just for Android.
Since I'm new to these frameworks (and to developing mobile apps in general), I need your an advice on the development process I should take:

Should I develop and test the Sencha Code on my PC browser and then, when the logic is completed and it look OK simply copy the resources to my Android/PhoneGap app and run on the mobile device? I mean, where and in what stage should I take parameters such as the screen size into consideration?
Any common obstacles I'm expected to find as a newbie to development in these 2 frameworks (combined)?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I've been developing a project using Sencha Touch since v1.0.0 and Phonegap since v0.95.
At first I would suggest keeping away from Android Emulator.(such a slow and problematic emulation)If you won't code any business logic that I mean your app won't depend on core mathematical abilities of java platform just using Ext-powered Sencha Touch you won't be able to test your work on a browser as well.My suggestion is starting and continuing on a real device-real mobile environment.Maybe you'll face various difficulties,problems that you can only see on a device and search for best practices while running your app on device.In addition to those I suggest you to build up an application flow mechanism using Sencha Touch's MVC samples.